# Is this the right way to compare strings in java?

Tags: java, string, equals

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Answer the following quiestions:");
      System.out.println("1-Which of these letters is not a vowel?");
    {
        String a = "a-A";
        String b = "b-I";
        String c = "c-W";//true
        String d = "d-O";
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);
        String answer1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(answer1);
        System.out.println(c.equals(answer1));



    }
```

When i compare two strings in java It keeps giving me a "False in the output even though it should be "true"

Comment: What did you enter as answer?

Comment: Well, what's your input? Is it "`c`"?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you expect an input of `c` from the user.

But your String `c` in the program is `c-W`. So your program would only show True, if the user would enter `c-W`.

Change your comparison to this:

```
System.out.println("c".equals(answer1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the case is correct, the "equals()" method is case sensitive so if you enter: "c-w" it will return false. If you don't want it to be case sensitive you just have to modify as below:

```
System.out.println(c.equalsIgnoreCase(answer1));
```